# cant save files via entity freamwork C# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have 2 clases product and file this lucks like this

```
 public  class Product
{
   public Product()
   {
       Image = new File();
   }
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
   public decimal SizeH { get; set; }
   public decimal SizeW { get; set; }
   public int Weight { get; set; }
   public string CPU { get; set; }
   public int Storage { get; set; }
   public string OpSys { get; set; }
   public int Price { get; set; }
  public  File Image { get; set; }
}
public  class File
{

   public int FileID { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
  public   byte[] FileData { get; set; }
}
```

Save product method is like this. I debugged it and information comes to this state in good condition, everything comes byte[] too, but after this only class file is not saved everything else saves OK

```
public void SaveProduct(Product product)
{
    if(product.ProductID==0)
    {
        context.Products.Add(product);
    }
    else
    {
        Product dbentry = context.Products.Find(product.ProductID);
        if (dbentry != null)
        {
             dbentry.Name = product.Name;
             dbentry.Manufacturer = product.Manufacturer;
             dbentry.OpSys = product.OpSys;
             dbentry.Price = product.Price;
             dbentry.SizeH = product.SizeH;
             dbentry.SizeW = product.SizeW;
             dbentry.Storage = product.Storage;
             dbentry.Weight = product.Weight;
             dbentry.Image = product.Image;
        }    
    }
context.SaveChanges();
```

}

Database looks like this 
http://s017.radikal.ru/i423/1411/5f/da9ffc9c233e.png

Comment: Are you sure your `product.Image` contains a valid entry from the DB?

Comment: How did you configured EF for Product -> File relationship? I see a Image_FileId field in Product table in DB, is it auto generated?

Comment: enty is not the problem problem is  if product is new and ID =0 there are context.Products.Add(product); and this is not working evryting exept Image are saved and displayd well too

Comment: it is avtogenrateid by entiti freamwork code ferst db set future here is code 
 public  class EFDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your File is being saved properly but just not loading properly due to the way EF implements lazy loading. Try one of the following:

1) Change the Image property on Product to be virtual. This will allow lazy loading to work properly.

```
public virtual File Image { get; set; }
```

2) When you are querying the context for a Product, provide EF with the Include hint so that it loads the Image property at the same time as it loads the Product. This strategy is called eager loading.

```
Product dbentry = context.Products.Include('Image').FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID);
```

Comment: i have not gotten to the editing files i have problems on the saving files with shis method if(product.ProductID==0)
    {
        context.Products.Add(product);
    }

Comment: Can you show us the contents of both the Products and Files tables?

Comment: what do you mean content this is the content just for testing but DB works 
http://www.picz.ge/img/s4/1411/26/d/d1c1072d0405.png